# View appearances of a certain character on different fonts

Tags: fonts, unicode, emoji

For some situation, especially when I choose some emoji or Unicode symbol for my application, it's significant to know the appearances of the character on different OS, that's the appearances on different fonts.

There are so many ways to view the appearances of characters in a certain font.
But in my question any suggestion for a way to view the appearances of a certain character on different fonts?

I mean, some convenient way, and I'm too lazy to install every font of each OS and click them one by one. I'm searching some easy way like that I type a character and then, wow, all appearances for major fonts are presented.

Comment: [Unicode codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) are system-agnostic.

Comment: @zx485, yeah, I know, so here I'm talking about the appearance in fonts.

Answer (score 0):

I found this website could view display on different OS.

https://unicode-table.com/en/3030/